# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'pthread_cond_t' with no type

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, gnustep

I'm getting some errors while trying to compile objective-c code that I didn't originally write. The platform is GNUstep on Windows 10. I'm very new to all this, so I suspect I'm making an elementary mistake.

Help!

**Compilation Errors:**

```
$ make
This is gnustep-make 2.6.5. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Making all for tool stockfish...
 Compiling file main.m ...
 Compiling file EngineController.mm ...
In file included from EngineController.mm:1:0:
EngineController.h:6:4: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'pthread_cond_t' with no type [-fpermissive]
EngineController.h:6:19: error: expected ';' before 'WaitCondition'
EngineController.h:7:4: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'pthread_mutex_t' with no type [-fpermissive]
EngineController.h:7:20: error: expected ';' before 'WaitConditionLock'
EngineController.mm: In function '-[EngineController initEngine]':
EngineController.mm:10:27: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
EngineController.mm:13:27: error: 'WaitConditionLock' was not declared in this scope
EngineController.mm:13:50: error: 'pthread_mutex_init' was not declared in this scope
EngineController.mm:14:26: error: 'WaitCondition' was not declared in this scope
EngineController.mm:14:45: error: 'pthread_cond_init' was not declared in this scope
EngineController.mm:18:12: warning: 'objc_object* objc_get_class(const char*)' is deprecated (declared at C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/objc/runtime-deprecated.h:30) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
make[3]: *** [obj/stockfish.obj/EngineController.mm.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [internal-tool-all_] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stockfish.all.tool.variables] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

**GNUmakefile**

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = stockfish
stockfish_OBJC_FILES = main.m
stockfish_OBJCC_FILES = EngineController.mm

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <pthread.h>
#import <EngineController.h>

int
main (void)
{ 

  [[Controller alloc] init];

  return 0;
}
```

**EngineController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Controller;

@interface EngineController : NSObject {
   pthread_cond_t WaitCondition;
   pthread_mutex_t WaitConditionLock;
   BOOL ignoreBestmove;
   BOOL engineThreadShouldStop;
   BOOL engineThreadIsRunning;
   BOOL engineIsThinking;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL engineIsThinking;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL engineThreadIsRunning;

- (void)initEngine;

@end

extern EngineController *GlobalEngineController;
```

**EngineController.mm**

```
#import "EngineController.h"

EngineController *GlobalEngineController;

@implementation EngineController

@synthesize engineIsThinking, engineThreadIsRunning;

- (void)initEngine {
   if (self = [super init]) {

      // Initialize locks and conditions
      pthread_mutex_init(&WaitConditionLock, NULL);
      pthread_cond_init(&WaitCondition, NULL);

      // Start engine thread
      NSThread *thread =
         [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget: self
                                 selector: @selector(startEngine:)
                                   object: nil];
      [thread setStackSize: 0x100000];
      [thread start];
      [thread release];

      ignoreBestmove = NO;
      engineIsThinking = NO;
   }
   GlobalEngineController = self;
}

@end
```

Comment: well, as a C++ programmer, as I can tell you is the *"C++ forbids declaration of 'pthread_cond_t' with no type"* message is probably caused by not including/importing the `pthread.h` header, but I'm not sure how you're expected to do that in objective-c.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I have attempted to do so with `#import <pthread.h>` in `main.m` - perhaps that isn't correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `discuss-gnustep` mailing list provided the solution: `#import <pthread.h>` was in the wrong place. It needed to be in `EngineController.h` instead of `main.m`